# How to paste Raw HTML into a README.md using markdown on GitHub?

Tags: html, github, markdown

Editing a README.md for a git repository. But I want to embed raw HTML into the the readme. I'm using Markdown, which is an excellent tool. Yet, the code just keeps showing up as rendered HTML.

How do I keep it Raw?
And formatted like code?

Here it is if you're curious:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Django Site</h1>
    <hr />
    <p>Thanks for visiting.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The heck? It works here.

Comment: it works when it's indented by at least four spaces.

Comment: Please always specify which markdown engine you are using on Md questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are on GitHub.

GitHub only allows certain HTML elements and attributes inside their markdown: all others are stripped to prevent XSS and defacing.

And of course, `<body>` is one of the forbidden tags as it would make the HTML invalid if present (a `body` inside a `body`)

This is documented at: https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/#html

Comment: Thank you, that article helped!

Comment: @TimReilly consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem (tick sign under vote count) ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to add html code to the readme file.

````
```html
<!-- sample html code  -->
<section id="produts"></section>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use "**`**" This Sign To Use Raw Code Snippets

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Django Site</h1>
        <hr />
        <p>Thanks for visiting.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

It Will Allow A User To Copy Your Code Directly From Your README.md File In Github By Just Pressing A Button !!!

Comment: you can put your links to your github repo, yt channel etc. into your profile, but please don't add it in an answer, unless you want it being flagged as spam. And please try to write in a normal style. In english uppercase is only used on the beginning of a sentence and for names, but not for every word.